# What is the decoded form of an instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel

I am reading through "What every computer scientist should know about memory" by Ulrich Drepper.

In section 6.2.2, it reads:

> [...] instructions  have  to  be  decoded  before
>   they  can  be  executed  and,  to  speed  this  up  (important
>   on x86 and x86-64), instructions are actually cached in
>   the decoded form, not in the byte/word form read from
>   memory.

What does the author means by a "decoded" form for an instruction? Aren't the instructions meaning what they mean on their own? A "add" is an "add" for instance...

What would be the representation of the its "decoded" form? Why does they need to cache it? Won't it be deterministic? Does it take to time to "decode" an instruction in the pipeline, and why?

Comment: Wiki explains that pretty well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit#Decode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern Intel CPUs actually implement many instructions using so-called [*microcode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode). Microcode consists of code written in a simpler low-level instruction set used to implement high-level instructions (for example, a `rep`-prefixed instruction might be implemented as a microcoded loop). Because this effectively requires the CPU itself to "compile" your input instruction stream into microcode, one can imagine that it is this microcode that is being cached (to avoid the overhead of repeatedly compiling it).

Of course, the precise details of caching "decoded" instructions varies greatly by processor, so no general statement is possible.

Comment: No, this isn't what Ulrich Drepper is talking about. He's talking about decoding instructions into micro-ops that are actually cached. For performance reasons, modern Intel processors actually use much less microcode than their predecessors.

Comment: ...what does Ulrich Drepper have to do with this conversation?

Comment: Drepper wrote the quote the question is asking about.  Opposite of what you wrote, generally only simple instructions (at most 4 uops) can be cached by the loop buffer in Intel CPUs (which existed in CPUs from 2007, when Drepper wrote that memory article).  It wasn't until Sandybridge (circa 2011) that Intel CPUs really started caching decoded uops in a more serious way, not just for the current loop.  (https://agner.org/optimize/). So I'm surprised that Drepper would put it that way; it's a lot more true now (SnB and Zen) than it was in 2007.

Comment: But anyway, complex instructions like rep movsb indirect to the microcode sequencer, and the uops from it aren't cached.  (The uop cache, aka DSB, in sandybridge can store that indirection, so the x86 machine code doesn't have to be re-decoded, though.)

Answer (score 3):

This is not the kind of decode step that you see in the classic RISC pipeline. In modern x86 processors, instructions go through several steps of decoding before they finally make it to the "generate control signals" stage. They are "predecoded" (identifying instruction boundaries), decoded into µops, then buffered, cached, and queued until they finally reach the "RISC-like core" where they are scheduled and put in reservation stations and only after that do they finally reach an ALU (if applicable). During most of that route they're probably not yet decoded in the classic RISC sense of "turned into actual control signals", that would make them too wide for it to make sense to put 1.5K of them in L1C. Anyway, those µops generated by the front end are the instruction set of the "RISC-like core", they're not true microcode in the old-fashioned sense of a state machine sequentially generating a bunch of control signals. It's comparable though.

As for what µops actually look like, it's really hard to get specifics. Some inferences can be made from the number of µops (and the ports they go to) generated by instructions, table found [here](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf). For example, read-operate and read-modify-write instructions are split into parts. Some instructions generate a huge number of µops, for example floating point transcedentals, making those instructions more like a kind of build-in functions probably implemented on top of other instructions. Instructions that do a variable amount of work also generate a variable number of µops, for example `rep movs`. So µops looks like RISC instructions, but then we already knew that.

Answer (score 2):

What you think of as a single instruction actually corresponds to (potentially) an entire set of different circuits on the processor.  "Decoded" means that the machine code is read, and some metadata or processor state now exists that selects the proper circuitry.  Caching that is more efficient than caching code.

For example, a load instruction might use one implementation for offset-addressing, and a completely different circuit for immediate addressing...

Answer (score 1):

The 3 steps a CPU always does are:

1. fetch (instruction from memory);
2. decode (the instruction - your question);
3. execute (let the electrical signal walk in the COU depending on the decoding stage).

Decoding an instruction means that the CPU "decoder" – which is a hardware component inside the CPU – decodes the binary instruction and decides how to deal with the electrical signal (the instruction) based on the instruction.

In other words: the instruction is converted to signals that control other parts of the CPU.